# ¿Como hacer un trigger que cuando se inserten datos en una tabla borre un registro de esa tabla?

Tags: mysql, trigger

estoy haciendo un trigger en mysql que elimine un registro de una tabla y se ejecute cuando se inserten datos es esa tabla lo hago de la siguiente manera

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `comp01`.`ELiminar***` 
 AFTER INSERT ON `comp01`.`<ft_inv_slvta>`
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM comp01.ft_inv_slvta WHERE codref = '***'
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Pero estoy teniendo problemas con la sintaxis del codigo

Al ejecutarlo salta este mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varios puntos a considerar:

- Necesita agregar `FOR EACH ROW`. Ver [14.1.20 CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html).

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `comp01`.`ELiminar***`
AFTER INSERT ON `comp01`.`<ft_inv_slvta>`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
...
```

- Opcionalmente, puede eliminar el `BEGIN` ... `END`, requerido cuando se ejecutan múltiples sentencias.
- Falta `;` al final de la sentencia `DELETE`.
- No puede actuar (`INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`) sobre la misma tabla que genera el disparador (trigger), obtendrá el error:

```sql
Can't update table '<ft_inv_slvta>' in stored function/trigger
because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

Ver ejemplo en [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h7KjAAdRcEiSAfQ7dFH3Wz/4).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `nombre_del_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `tu_tabla`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET @A = 1;  //variable x puedes meter una consulta o x valor
  IF (NEW.campo IS NOT NULL) THEN
    set @variable1 := NEW.id; //Estos son los valores del nuevo registro que se insertó
    set @variable2 := NEW.campo;

    DELETE FROM tu_tabla WHERE id = @variable1;
  END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

a mi me funcionó de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `comp01`.`ELiminar***` 
AFTER INSERT ON `comp01`.`ft_inv_slvta`
FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM comp01.ft_inv_slvta WHERE codref = '***'
```

Comment: ¿Puede insertar en la tabla `ft_inv_slvta`?.

Comment: Necesito la estructura de la BD

Comment: Trate con una estructura simple, por ejemplo, [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h7KjAAdRcEiSAfQ7dFH3Wz/4).

Comment: No se inserta en la msmaNo corre el insert porque a la vez tratas de borrarlo.
Manda:
#1442 - Can't update table '<ft_inv_slvta>' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: Ya investigué y no se puede hacer, para eso necesitas hacerlo como un procesos externo a la base de datos. Saludos!